# Missing interpolation argument error in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

A bit of Googling led me to believe that this error happens in Rails Version < 2.3.6 . 
So i changed my environment file to

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Now, I have 2 questions .

1. I continue to get the redmine error.
2. When I do a script/server, I get this :
   Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000

even though I've clearly instructed it to load Rails 2.3.8 ! Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: Which release of Redmine do you use? There is a list in the Redmine wiki which lists the Redmine version in accordance to the Rails versions.

Comment: What is the result when `RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8'` (after removing the `unless....` part? Also, this does not seem to be a RedMine error per se. Maybe some plugin you're using?

Comment: @khmarbaise - I'm using Redmine-1.0.0. I saw the wiki, and there doesn't seem to be redmine package for Rails 2.3.8.  @Zabba - Same message even after removing the unless part. And plugins are only application-wide. So I don't think that's the problem . And I haven't come across any gems that Redmine is not compatible with .

Comment: Why are you using a different Rails version than stated in the docs? The docs saying Rails 2.3.5 so why not using it? If it is really producing a failure you should raise an issue in the tracking system.

Comment: I tried using Rails 2.3.8 because I learned that problem does not exist in versions > 2.3.6 . Anyway, I'm using Redmine 1.0.2, and so far haven't faced the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, Redmine currently supports Rails 2.3.5 **only**. Any other version (including 2.3.8) will cause issues. So don't use them.

The error you mentioned is caused by the i18n gem >= 0.4. In recent 1.0 releases this issue should be fixed. A workaround was committed to trunk in [r4183](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/4183) which was pulled into 1.0 stable in [r4202](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/4202). So updating to a recent 1.0.x release (current version is 1.0.2) should fix the issue. See the Redmine issue [#6428](http://www.redmine.org/issues/6428) for more information.

Another possibility would be to just remove the i18n gem completely, as it is not needed by Rails 2.3.5 nor Redmine.